# I have an error when adding data in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem adding **firebase** data. I have this error

> Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  contains an invalid
>   key (__reactInternalInstance$5a2c5dfp3mw) in property
>   'part.537507.type._targetInst.stateNode'.  Keys must be non-empty
>   strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

The error

> 57 |        firebase.database().ref('part/' + key).update({

key = 578451 //  A number with 6 digits

```
firebase.database().ref('part/' + key).update({
   id: key,
   player1: this.state.pseudo,
   player2: null,
   player1_time: null,
   player2_time: null,
   part_started_at: null,
   point: point,
   type: type
});
```

At the moment I have this error is I do not know how to solve it. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `key` only accepts `string` or `null` and your key value is in `numeric form` - See - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference. So, first convert your key to string using `key.toString()`.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i hve the seem problem

i have change this
```
firebase.database().ref('part/' + key.toString()).update({
            id: key.toString(),
            player1: this.state.pseudo,
            part_started_at: null,
            point: point,
            type: type
        });
```

Comment: The error is showing `part.537507.type._targetInst.stateNode` in this part. The numeric properties cannot be accessed with  `dot` operator i:e const arr = ["item"]. In this case, arr.0 will give error, instead for numeric properties square brackets are required (arr[0]). So, `part.537507` will not work. Try passing `key` enclosing it into the square brackets. i:e `firebase.database().ref('part/' + [key.toString()]).update({`.

Comment: But, I can see one difference your key value is `578451` and in error section it is `537507`. It seems like error is occurring somewhere else.

Comment: The error is still the.
firebase.database().ref('part/' + [key.toString()]).update({
            id: key,
            player1: this.state.pseudo,
            part_started_at: null,
            point: point,
            type: type
        });
And for the difference of the key it's because key is random

Comment: And i have test this code

firebase.database().ref('part/554555').update({
            id: key,
            player1: this.state.pseudo,
            part_started_at: null,
            point: point,
            type: type
        });

And the error is the same. I don't think the error comes from [key.toString()]

Comment: I found the error, in my function i have an arguments type. And it contains the variable of a class. It's a mistake on my part sorry. Thank for your time :)